# How can I use / in strings in java?

Tags: java

I would like to know how I can use `/` in java because it doesn't consider it as a simple `/` .

Comment: With an escape char: "\". Show some research effort. As mentioned below though, "/" usually doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape \ to \\ in strings.  / should be fine though.

Answer (score 1):

There are no problems using `/` in a string in Java.  It just works.  (If it is not working for you, it is 99.9999% likely that there's a bug in your code.  Show us the problem in an SSCCE.)

If you were talking about `\` ... that is a different matter.  The `\` character is the escape character for String (and character) literals in Java source code.  So if you want to put a (single) backslash into a String, you need to write it like this:

```
    String message = "This string contains ONE backslash (\\)";
```

However this only applies to *literals*.  In the actual runtime representation of a string (e.g. above), a backslash is one character ... not two.  Similarly, when you read text from a file or from the user, a backslash will be represented as one character ... and there is no need to either escape or unescape it to put it into a String.

The escaping of backslashes in regular strings ONLY applies to the string literal form ... in Java source code.  (Regexes are another matter ... but we are not talking about that.)

Answer (score 0):

`/` is okay for use in Strings: `String string = "0/100"`
However, `\` is an escape key. That means that the next letter will determine what special character it is. e.g, `\n` is `newline`.

To use `\` literally in strings, you'll have to use `\\`.

E.g.

```
String string = "0\\100";
System.out.println(string);
```

will print `0\100`.